# Can I install both - Eclipse Classic and Eclipse for Jave EE?

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to install both - Eclipse Classic and Eclipse for Java EE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, choose different installation directories and you can have as many different Eclipse instances as you have space for.

Be careful running multiple instances at the same time though. Unless you have a huge amount of memory on your machine, performance will grind down because of swapping.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You're not installing Eclipse but just unpacking and running, so there is no limit.